# PHP: getting calculation issue in the for loop

Tags: php, loops

Sorry for this silly question.
I want to spend 25 credits of my available credit is 30(10,10,10). But in my below sample code, the final amount is getting minus(-) 5 value instead of 5. Could you please check my code, actualy output and my expected result:

Code:

```
<?php
$content_credit = 25;
$data = array(10,10,10);
$used_credit = 0;
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
    if($content_credit > $used_credit){
        $used_credit += $data[$i];
        echo "Point: " . $data[$i];
        echo " Used: " . $used_credit;
        echo " Remaining: " . ($content_credit - $used_credit);
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Actual Result:

```
Point: 10 Used: 10 Remaining: 15
Point: 10 Used: 20 Remaining: 5
Point: 10 Used: 30 Remaining: -5
```

Expected Result:

```
Point: 10 Used: 10 Remaining: 15
Point: 10 Used: 20 Remaining: 5
Point: 10 Used: 25 Remaining: 5
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add another condition to the `if()` statement to check the remaining value before "redeeming" the credit?

Comment: Surely the expected result should be `10, 10, 20; 10, 20, 10; 5, 25, 5` if your available credit is 10+10+10?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code? As it is written nowl you will always increase the used credit by 10. And decrease the remaining amount by 10. So, in the last iteration 25 > 20, and the end result is 5 - 10 = -5

Comment: `$used_credit += $data[$i];` how adding 10 (the third item in the array) to 20 (`$used_credit` from the previous iteration) you can get expected result of 25?

Answer (score 2):

`$content_credit` in first iteration becomes 10, then in second it become 20 due to the `+=`.

Hence 25 - 10 - 20 = -5

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
<?php
$content_credit = 25;
$data = array(10,10,10);
$total = array_sum($data);
$used_credit = 0;
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
    if($content_credit > $used_credit){
        $used_credit += $data[$i];
        echo "Point: " . $data[$i];
        echo " Used: " . $used_credit;
        $remaining = $used_credit > $content_credit ? $total - $content_credit :  $total - $used_credit;
        echo " Remaining: " . $remaining;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

You need to know how much credit you have in total to calculate the remainings.

To get the amount of actual credit used it is enough to know which value is smaller between `$used_credit` and `$content_credit`. So you can use `min()` to get the value.

```
echo " Used: " . min($used_credit, $content_credit);
```

Similarly the `$remaining` can be replaced with `max()` value of the ternary operator results or a simple calculation `$total - $actual_used`.

```
echo " Remaining: " . max($total - $content_credit,  $total - $used_credit);
```

Comment: Last one `Used: 30`  should be `Used: 25`

Comment: @Chinmay235 added solution for that

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$credit_to_spend = 25;
$available_credit = array(10,10,10);
$used_credit = 0;

for( $i=0; $i<count($available_credit); $i++ ){
    if( $credit_to_spend > $used_credit ){

        $required = ($credit_to_spend - $used_credit);
        $used_credit += ($required < $available_credit[$i]) ? $required : $available_credit[$i];
        $remaining = (($required < $available_credit[$i]) ? ($available_credit[$i] - $required): ($credit_to_spend - $used_credit));

        echo "Point: " . $available_credit[$i] 
        . " Used: " . $used_credit 
        . " Remaining: " . $remaining;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```